# Facing problem with menu item component after migrating to react material v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

After migrating to react material UI version 5. All the menu item components (Select and Menu's) are getting displayed linearly. I am unable to find the reason for this?
[Here's a link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lUIR.png)

In the above Image all menu options should be displayed vertically one below the other but they are getting displayed in on row.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: v4 and v5 use different style libraries (JSS vs emotion), you should not mix the code between 2 versions together.

Comment: @thecoder-elite Please show me your code, even better is to put it on Codesandbox.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.